# Change one list using a key list

Tags: python, list, loops, replace

I have two lists.

One is the key list (has the values I want)

The other has values I want to replace if they don't match the other list perfectly
     (Has additional text, doesn't match perfectly)

Example:

```
List 1 (key list)  = [Pepsi, Coca-Cola, Coca-Cola Flav, Mountain Dew]
List 2 (mod list) = [Pepsi - labeled,  Coca-Cola, Coca-Cola Flavored, Mountain Dew]
```

I want to replace list two to match list one if it doesn't match exactly.

If they match exactly, I guess they can be replaced if it makes the code easier. Doesn't matter to me.

Comment: can you please show what you have tried

Comment: ...Why not just substitute list 1 for list 2, if what you want is for list 2 to match list 1 anyway?

Comment: I'm not clear about your objective, but maybe you could utilize set operations like union / intersection.  Please clarify your goal because it sounds like, as Green Cloak Guy stated, that you may just want to substitute list 1 for list 2.

Comment: Sorry, the lists are tied to other sales data. So, I need to make sure I can sum all of the sales data by Product name. So I need the two data sheets to have the same product names. And list one is the key and list 2 is the product list I need to modify so I can merge the data and sum all sales and profitability numbers for a certain time period

Answer (score 0):

you can use [list.copy](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
list2 = list1.copy()
```